# Removing punctuation from string of characters

Tags: c++, c++11

There is an exercise in the book [C++ Primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Primer) *(number 3.2.3)* which asks:

> Write a program that reads a string of characters including punctuation and writes what was read but with the punctuation removed.

I attempted to solve it, but got an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> "Enter a sentence :" >> s >> endl;
    for (auto c : s)
         if (ispunct(c))
            remove punct;
        cout << s << endl;


    }
```

Comment: ... and what precisely is the error?

Comment: You should use braces around your `if` and `for` statements to avoid ambiguity. Also, `remove punct` makes no sense.

Comment: As you could see, the question doesn't require you to store the result. You traverse every character one by one, why not just write the each character one after another if it is not a punctuation?

Comment: error: cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'|

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı can you please give the solution ?

Comment: You aren't going to learn anything if someone just hands you the solution. You'll probably want to use `std::getline` instead of streaming in data via `operator>>`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I am programming in C++11 , so I dont think there is a need to use std::getline

Comment: _"I dont think"_ - famous last words.

Comment: If someone asked you to write a word processor...would you think a traditional compiler would be able to understand a program like **while (user makes input) { process the words; }**?  Perhaps the likes of Google and Siri have given you the impression that you can just write **remove punct;** or **remove punct if (it is either a period or a comma);**.  But putting parentheses after an `if` doesn't magically allow you to write anything you want as a condition, nor does putting a semicolon at the end of a line of text make it "code".  The language has rules.  The book is for learning them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `remove_if()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;

    getline(std::cin,s);

    cout << s << endl;
    s.erase (std::remove_if(s.begin (), s.end (), ispunct), s.end ());
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: I love this idea, but I get a compiler error when I try to use this.  "error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if'..."

Comment: @Trenin, what is the compiler you're using?

Comment: g++ gcc version 6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2)

Comment: @Trenin Try changing `ispunct` to `::ispunct`?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> "Enter a sentence : " >> s >> endl;
    for (auto c : s)
        if (ispunct(c))
            remove punct;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Your first issue is that you're using `cin` the wrong way. `cin` is used for standard *input* so it makes no sense to try and print a string and a newline. This is a job for `cout`:

```
cout << "Enter a sentence : ";
cin >> s;
cout << endl;
```

The other problem is that `remove punct` as a statement doesn't mean anything to the compiler. It's a syntax error. Since you want to print the string without punctuation, just print only if `ispunct()` returned false:

```
for (auto c : s)
{
    if (!ispunct(c)) {
        cout << c;
    }
}
```

Also remember to use braces to avoid ambiguity.